# Solving for $\cos a$

Tags: trigonometry

Given that

$\sin(\frac{a}{2})=\frac{1}{4}$ and $405^{\circ} < \frac{a}{2} < 450^{\circ}$ find  $\cos a$

I tried the following

$\sin \frac{a}{2} = \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos a}{2}} \Longrightarrow \frac{1}{4}=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos a}{2}} \Longrightarrow \frac{1}{16} = \frac{1 - \cos a}{2} \Longrightarrow \cos a = \frac {7}{8}$

however, the answer key says the answer is supposed to be $-\frac{\sqrt{8+2\sqrt{15}}}{4}$

How is that answer achieved?

Answer (score 2):

We have: $0 < \cos(\frac{a}{2}) = \sqrt{1-\sin^2(\frac{a}{2})}=...$, and $\cos a = 2\cos^2(\frac{a}{2}) - 1 = .....$
note that you need not have $405^{\circ} < \dfrac{a}{2} < 450^{\circ}$ to find $\cos a$, and you might just apply immediately the formula $\cos a =  1- 2\sin^2 (\frac{a}{2}) = 1-2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2 = 1 - \frac{1}{8} = \dfrac{7}{8}$

Comment: Are you saying that I have the correct answer?

Comment: Certainly. Your answer is right....